# I can't install kivy via pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

I'm trying to switch from Tkinter since I heard that Kivy has better UI's so I go on the Kivy website and look on how to install it.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

I follow all windows installation instructions.

Python Version: 3.8.2
Pip Version: 20.1
Operating System: Windows 10

I first try to install via pip and python and I get an error. I then try to install via pip3 and python3 since that's what I usually do but it still doesn't work...

Please help me, I don't want to use anaconda since that's the only thing I see that could work.

Here is the error I get:

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'c:\users\dogiy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dogiy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-efqf4e5m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dogiy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-efqf4e5m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dogiy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gu87fh1a\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\dogiy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.`

I'm not sure what to do... Can someone help me?

Comment: I think the error because kivy still not support python 3.8.0, downgrade python version to 3.7.    Github_link: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy+pip

Answer (score 1):

I was using `Python 3.8.2` when it is not compatible with that version of `Kivy` so I downgraded to the latest version of `Python 3.7 (3.7.7)` and it works now :)